# Get the event of Radio defined with Assign

Tags: autoit

I have an application with a Radio Group. The number of Radio is not defined so i had to assign them one by one with the following code :

```
$CmdList = _FileListToArray($CmdDir)
If @error == 0 Then
    for $i = 1 To $CmdList[0]
        Assign("Radio"&$i, GUICtrlCreateRadio(StringSplit($CmdList[$i], ".")[1], 20 + (100 + 10)*$i, 35, 100, 20))
    Next
Else
    ConsoleWrite("error directory path")
EndIf
```

So, i have Radio1, Radio2, ...

To control events, i use the following structure :

```
While 1
    $nMsg = GUIGetMsg()
    Switch $nMsg
        Case $GUI_EVENT_CLOSE
            Exit

        [...]

    EndSwitch
WEnd
```

How can i define a function to call when i click on a Radio ? Because i can't define a *Case $Radio1, Case $Radio2, ...*

**Edit** : By adding a *Case Eval("Radio1")*, it works. Is there a way to generate cases for a switch ?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution :

```
Case Eval("Radio"&1) to Eval("Radio"&$NumberRadio)
```

It works !